# docker registry v2 ui with docker_auth

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have the *registry v2* container and *docker_auth* up and running. The registry uses self sign certificate which was created with my CA. I can pull and push images without any problem so the configuration is working properly.

I would like to have a UI for this registry to browse images. I have tried many of them:

- https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend not support token based auth
- https://shipyard-project.com only supports v1 registries
- https://github.com/SUSE/Portus looks quite heavy weight for me
- https://github.com/mkuchin/docker-registry-web i configure it with my keyfile and set the issuer. But i couldn't add my repo, it always returns 401. In the docker registry i found "token intended for another audience: \"mydockerrepo:5000\"". I tried with different names but none of them worked. I check the crt and key files and i use the correct crt-key pair.

Is there any other UI i should try?

Can somebody help me with the "audience" error message?

Comment: Ok, i got the problem with the "docker-registry-web", there is a misleading comment and the "name" in the config should math with auth.token.service value. But other ui project suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can also look at this one https://github.com/Evedel/bow. Of course, it is adv of my own registry frontend =), but it fully covers my needs, may be it will cover yours so far.

Comment: @Kemy - it looks to me like https://github.com/mkuchin/docker-registry-web  is intended to act as the authorization service itself. Where you able to make this work with a different authorization server?

Comment: @Evedel - it looks like Bow doesn't support the Bearer Token authorization for the v2 registry. The code appears to simply send basic auth to the registry.

Comment: @JohnEngelman, ohhh, yeah, you completely right, sorry, I thought that the question was about v2 auth itself. But you push me to a good idea =) Think, I'll be able to add it in a week or two.

Comment: @JohnEngelman yeah, i have three different running container. One is the registry, one is the docker_auth service and the third is the registry-web. The registry-web can authenticate with the docker_auth and it can list the images in the docker registry.